# Control Two agents separately with one script?

Tags: unity

I have two characters"agent" moving them on terrain by mouse. My script for both of them is...

```
public Vector3 point_;
public float mark;
public float mark;
public UI_Button _active_character; // butoon select script

void Update 
{

  Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit mousePoint;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out mousePoint, 100) )
        {
            point_ = mousePoint.point;
            mAgent.SetDestination(mousePoint.point);
            mark = Vector3.Distance(point_, gameObject.transform.position);
        }
    }
 }
```

Here script for character buttons. Every character has it own button.

```
public bool character1, character2;

void Start()
{
    character1 = true;

}

   void Update()
{

    if (character1 == true)
    {
        character2 = false;
    }

    if (character2 == true)
    {
        character1 = false;
    }

   if (character1 == fale && character2 == false)
    {
    // Later. free cam moving...
    }

}

public void avatar1_click() // button 
{
    character1 = !character1;
    character2 = false;

}
public void avatar2_click() // button
{
    character2 = !character2;
    character1 = false;
}
```

It's possible to control both of them separately by one script by click on button to chose character ?

Comment: your naming conventions hurt my heart :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to adjust first script and make it identify which player "object" is active when click.

```
   if (_active_character.character1 == true && this.gameObject.name == "Player1 Object Name")
    {
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit mousePoint;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out mousePoint, 100))
            {
                point_ = mousePoint.point;
                this.mAgent.SetDestination(mousePoint.point);
                mark = Vector3.Distance(point_, gameObject.transform.position);
            }
        }

    }

if (_active_character.character2 == true && this.gameObject.name == "Player2 Object Name")
    {
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit mousePoint;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out mousePoint, 100))
            {
                point_ = mousePoint.point;
                this.mAgent.SetDestination(mousePoint.point);
                mark = Vector3.Distance(point_, gameObject.transform.position);
            }
        }

    }
```